# How can I skip a generic argument?

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

Can somebody help me with this issue?

I have a some class, which I can't change.
Like this:

```
public class SomeBaseClass<T1, T2>
    where T2 : SomeBaseClass<T1, T2>
{ }
```

And I've made a child class:

```
public class SomeConcretClass : SomeBaseClass<int, SomeConcretClass>
{  }
```

Now, I want to create a factory for instantiate this classes.
Like this:

```
public class SomeFactory
{
    public T2 CreateSome<T1, T2>()
        where T2 : SomeBaseClass<T1, T2>, new()
    {
        return new T2();
    }
}
```

As you can see, I need to use the T1 generic argument only for using it in the **where** construction, but it don't use in the factory method body.
I want to implement Create method, like this:

```
public T2 CreateSome<T2>()
        where T2 : SomeBaseClass<, T2>, new()
    {
        return new T2();
    }
```

But I can't do this, because of C# restrictions. Is there some way to implement method, like I've described before with the where construction and without using the generic argument, or there is only one way - using Create method with only one generic argument and use reflection in method body to instantiate concrete class. If the second option is true, could somebody help me with correct using reflection in this case?

Comment: Your second generic argument is self referencing. E.g. `T2` is specified as `SomeBaseClass<T1, T2>` which is itself, nested. Are you sure the code sample is accurate?

Comment: Yes, it's simplification from real project, and I can't change this base class. This way is used for implement some type of fluent behavior inside the base class.

Answer (score 0):

> I need to use the T1 generic argument only for using it in the where construction, but it don't use in the factory method body

Maybe not, but `T1` is a required type parameter on `SomeBaseClass<T1, T2>`. It's impossible for the compiler to infer what type `T1` should be here unless you tell it. `SomeBaseClass<_unknown_, T2>` is not allowed.

If you happen to know at design time what type `T1` will be then, yes, you can hard-code as below, but otherwise no, that `T1` cannot be refactored away.

```
public T2 CreateSome<T2>()
    where T2 : SomeBaseClass<int, T2>, new()
{
    return new T2();
}
```

Comment: I understand this, but I don't know what type of T1 at design time.